# Is there a CSS selector to select html elements that begin with certain letters?

Tags: html, css

I'm aware that there are selectors to find html attribute-values that begin with something, e.g. `bar`:

```
[class^=bar] { ... }
```

Is there a way to select html elements that begin with a certain text, such as `<my-calendar>, <my-contact>, ...`:

```
my-* { ... }
```

Or is there a proposed selector in a future CSS specification (for the new custom elements, for example)?

**Edit: Since many people are proposing alternative solutions:**

I am just asking out of curiosity for future projects and I am aware that there are many other ways of handling this today.

Comment: Basically you are referring to custom elements and there is no such selector now or planned that I am aware of,

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `my-calendar, my-contact, ... { ... }`? Are you really creating so many unique tag names on the fly that you don't have a predefined set of tags?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To select a group of custom elements, starting with a particular namespace. (Of course I could just use classes or data attributes, which I will end up doing, but I wanted to know if this was considered in light of custom elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Sort of, via Namespaces.

If you give all of your tags the same namespace, you should be able to target them via `namespace|*`. Probably. The only official documentation I could find is the spec itself: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-namespaces-3/ 
And trying to make sense of it is hard- [the (very) naive approach doesn't work basically at all](http://dabblet.com/gist/1ed430090f40dbca684e). This is because @namespace designates the url as the set, and the prefix is just an internal name for it.

I'll probably revisit this answer later once I've figured out how the hell namespaces work- this isn't something that I've really ever needed before, but it is something that I should know- especially now.

---

Long answer: Yes? I think?

Beyond Namespaces in CSS3...

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/

There's something *close* to what you're wanting with the planned `:matches()` selector, however, you'll still need to explicitly state every tag you want. You can just group all of your tags instead of having to repeat the entire selector for each one.

You also might be able to bs something with `:scope`, however, I'm not overly clear on what exactly it's doing.

Personally I find tag-based selection to be somewhat of a Bad Thing outside of changing browser defaults and a page's lone table (which I honestly still overuse due to how quick they are to get right and the fact that `table-layout:fixed` makes them about 200x less terrible... plus my job is mostly converting paper/Access forms into web forms, which means I'm actually working with a lot of actually-tabular data). You should really be giving all of those tags of yours a default layout explicitly, and then use classes to group them.

Attribute selectors are not to substitute classes, by the way. They're to extend precision. Stop abusing them.

EDIT: since there was a question as to what I meant by that last line...

- `tagname` is a very blanket selector, it hits every instance of a tag. Hence, it semantically means something like 'these are the default settings of this tag'.
- `#id` means 'this specific element' and `.class` means 'any of this class'. The former is about as specific as you can get, and the latter was originally added to be THE way of targetting only certain elements. As such, these are your workhorse selectors, they are the most performant and the most semantically correct for styling.
- `[attribute]` was added to increase specificity. Say you want only links using http to be nixed: `a[href^="http:"]{display:none;}`. Another use is for shorthand, with the best example being the hidden shim of `[hidden]{display:none;}`. Additionally you can use it for quick-and-dirty hacks- say you notice an image is off-center by two pixels. Instead of recentering it in your image editor, you can have the browser fix it via `img[src="image_path"]{position:relative;left:2px;}`.
   However, no matter how you use it, it is a form of ***merging style and data***. Merging style and data is *usually* a Bad Thing, as data changes often while the kind of data, thus the needed style does not. Thus, you should avoid doing so unless it's simply too convenient not to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence. What do you mean with *extend precision*?

Comment: @nils `tag` is supposed to be a 'defaults' selector, with `#id` and `.class` being your workhorse selectors. These are the semantic meanings. Attributes are primarily a form of data, not style descriptors. Thus, the `[attribute]` selectors are for precision (any links to x should be fancy `a[href^="x"]{ ... }` shorthands (such as pre-official hidden as `[hidden]{display:none;}`), and hacks/shims (ex: transparent image x is 2px off center `img[src="x"]{position:relative;left:-2px;}`). 90% of the time if you're not using an attribute selector for one of those things, you're using it wrong.

Comment: @nils This is supported by performance.... Speed of selection has `#id` being the fastest, and `.class` on its tail.

Comment: This seems to have been originally intended (mainly using elements, ids and classes). Not using attribute selectors for class ranges seems to be mainly opinion-based though (selector-perfomance at this scale barely matters unless you do crazy-deep nesting). So calling it "abuse" seems a bit far-fetched. Specificity might be another argument against attribute selectors though (and very much against IDs as well).

Comment: @Nils Fair 'nuff on "effectively opinion", however I do stand by Attributes are inherently data, and styling based on data is always questionable for the same reason you shouldn't use data-based keys in SQL. Data changes. IMO the OP's use case sounds like the use case `.class` was specifically created to address- "I need all of a specific set of tags designated to have this style". Using an attribute instead is just hacky for no reason. As for speed, being negligible, optimization for web-stuff tends towards semantically correct, only reason I mentioned it. otherwise... `[class*="..."]`

Comment: Fair enough reasoning :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97438/discussion-between-abluejelly-and-nils).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) there isn't.

But you can get this using attributes `my-contact[attribute^="something"]`

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, there is no selector to do this. You can however use the jQuery .data() method to retrieve data defined by using the data-* attribute. You just need to target the data element using the name you assigned it after the dash. This gets passed as a string to the data() method.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo" data-bar="abc"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var yourdata = $('#foo').data('bar') //abc
```

Comment: What does data have to do with any of this?

Comment: Why is it "unfortunate", when there is no need for it? Assuming I wanted to use a data attribute instead, why would I use jQuery instead of just saying `element.dataset.bar` or `element["data-bar"]`?

Comment: His question was, "is there a way to select html elements that begin with a certain text, such as <my-calendar>, <my-contact>, ...:" to which the answer is no - there is no wildcard to select an element the way the question is being asked. There are use cases where this would be helpful (searching for and targeting elements by wildcard), but you have to rely on scripting instead.

Comment: @DannyGibas You seem to have the right idea in that comment of yours, but your answer is for a completely different problem, as well as uses jQ for absolutely no reason whatsoever. If I could -2 I would.